# libesmtp and file attach

Tags: c, smtp

I can attach a file with libesmtp?

Does anyone have a sample code?

Thanks

FrankIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The library only covers the SMTP protocol, the communication with the server.  It does nothing to help you construct a valid MIME document.